# How can i get the character of a key code

Tags: javascript, keycode

I have some code which captures a key.

Now i have in event.code the real key-name and in event.key i get the key-char.
To make an example: I press SHIFT and J, so i get:
*event.code: SHIFT KEYJ*
*event.key: J*

So, i get in event.key the "interpreted key" from shift J. But now i need to convert the native key to a char. So i am looking for a solution to get from "KEYJ" to a char, that means "j". How can this be done? I have not found anything about this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: event.key.toLowerCase() ?

Comment: That will work for normal chars, but not for special chars, e.g. shift #

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Optional chaining (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

```js
document.querySelector("[type=text]").addEventListener("keypress",function(e) {
  console.log(
  e.key,
  e.key?.toLowerCase(),
  e.shiftKey,
  e.altKey,
  e.code
  )
})
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

No, sorry, you missunderstood. The problem is not the lowercase for normal chars. I want to get the char for all keys without the "Shift". So, i want at using "shift #" not the " ' ". I want to get back to the real key. So i have to get the char value  for the key from event.code. In this case i get "Backslash"  from event.code. What key is Backslash without shift? With shift i get this via event.key, i know.

Comment: Hi, in future if you are responding to an answer please try to do so in the form of a comment on the answer rather than a separate answer. That way the person posting the answer will get a notification and the thread will be clearer to people looking in the future.